# How to hide Business Process Flow in dynamics crm?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a cusotn entity, on my custom entity form I added a  Business Process Flow , my need is: after the user chooses a specific value from a field (on the form) to show/hide my workflow, using Js OR customzation, is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can use following code to hide business process flow:

```
Xrm.Page.ui.process.setVisible(false);
```